# Call to simple service fails with an apparently erroneous error message

Tags: c#, wcf

When I call this service, I got this error message:

> ContractDescription has zero operations; a contract must have at least
>   one operation

It makes no sense since my interface's function has the `[OperationContract()]` attribute defined.

**The interface:**

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface ITest
{

    [OperationContract()]
    bool Connect(string password);

}
```

**The SVC:**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="CS" Debug="true" Service="TestService.Test" CodeBehind="Test.svc.cs" %>
```

**The svc.cs:**

```
public class Test : ITest
{

public bool Connect(string password)
{
    return true;
}

}
```

**The call:** *the configuration is defined programatically because it is a library*

```
public sealed class Validator
{

    public static bool Connect(string password)
    {
        return ObtenirCLient().Connect(password);
    }

    private static LicensingService.LLMrqLicensingClient ObtenirCLient()
    {
        dynamic endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/TestService/Test.svc");
        LicensingService.LLMrqLicensingClient client = new LicensingService.LLMrqLicensingClient(ObtenirBinding(), endpoint);

        client.Endpoint.Name = "LicHttp";
        client.Endpoint.Contract = new Description.ContractDescription("TestService.ITest");

        return client;
    }

    private static BasicHttpBinding ObtenirBinding()
    {
        return new BasicHttpBinding {
            Name = "LicHttp",
            Security = ObtenirSecurity()
        };
    }

    private static BasicHttpSecurity ObtenirSecurity()
    {
        return new BasicHttpSecurity {
            Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly,
            Transport = ObtenirTransport()
        };
    }

    private static HttpTransportSecurity ObtenirTransport()
    {
        return new HttpTransportSecurity { ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows };
    }

}
```

If you see anything strange, please let me know!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
client.Endpoint.Contract = new Description.ContractDescription("TestService.ITest");
```

Try this:

```
client.Endpoint.Contract = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(ITest));
```

Comment: That fixes the problem for me though I have another. Thanks for the help, I went a step further!